# How to restrict access to my server from the Tor Network AND Browser?

Tags: networking, permissions, .htaccess, tor

I am working on a secure application, and for security and other purposes, I would like that people not be able to access my site via the `Tor Network` AND the `Tor Browser`.

I am using an server based on the `LAMP Stack` with `.htaccess` enabled.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Comment: If you have access to the main server config there is no good reason to use a .htaccess file.

Comment: I use .htaccess mainly for non-www to www redirection.. and redirecting from my AWS EC2/ELB DNS to my Domain Name

Comment: you really don't need to use .htaccess for that.